# PHP - Matching search terms mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, search, match

im having issue with a php script that retrieves values from a database and see's which ones match an input term. I either get the resourceID #4 error or no response.

Im basically trying to retrieve similar entries and of those similar entries show the name and date of their submission

```
$input = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["interest"]);
$query1 = "SELECT name,interest_desc,date, MATCH(interest_desc) AGAINST('$input') AS score
 FROM interests
 WHERE MATCH(interest_desc) AGAINST('$input')
 ORDER BY score DESC
 LIMIT 10
 ";

 $result = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo $row['name'];
 echo $row['interest_desc'];
echo $row['date'];
 }
```

I must be going wrong with my syntax, any pointers? im pulling my hair out over this!

Comment: It looks like a problem with your SQL. Have you run your query against your database (like in phpMyAdmin, or something)? What does `mysql_error()` say, if anything?

Comment: The SQL is, in fact, **correct**. Your problem is almost certainly solved in this existing SO post: **[MySQL FULLTEXT Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125678/mysql-fulltext-not-working)**

Comment: needed to be in boolean mode. got it working now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you indexed the field as full text and is your table myisam. See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) for more detail.