# MATCH ... LIKE returns nothing

Tags: mysql, myisam

I'm trying to create my own blog in CodeIgniter.
One key feature of a blog, is that you can search for posts by using some keywords.
These keywords must be found in the title, content, category and/or keywords.

I'm still working on my database (e.g. extracting category and keywords into seperate tables), but this is what I've got so far

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `titel` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `content` (`content`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `keywords` (`keywords`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

*I'm not sure about the content column, probably should use `text` instead of `varchar(10000)`*

In my table, I have 2 posts

```
ID | TITLE                        | CONTENT          | DATA       | KEYWORDS       | CATEGORY
---+------------------------------+------------------+------------+----------------+----------------------
 1 | Welcome to my website        | A few paragraphs | 2014-02-09 | Welcome        | Site
 2 | All Windows Keyboard layouts | A few paragraphs | 2014-03-11 | A few keywords | Windows Deployment
```

My query is as follow, I tried to keep is as simple as possible for now

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `posts`
    WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('Welcome');
```

I can't seem to figure out why phpMyAdmin doesn't return a thing.

I also tried a more complex query to see if it returns anything, without any luck

```
SELECT *, MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('Welcome') AS Relevance
    FROM `posts`
    WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('Welcome')
    ORDER BY `Relevance` DESC
```

If I understand correctly, `MATCH x AGAINST y` can be with multiple keywords.
That's what I'm looking for. I want to be able to add a couple of keywords to the query and find the posts that score highest relevance in title, content, keywords and category

Comment: What if you remove `WHERE` from the last query?

Comment: @zerkms Then I get the complete table (because of the `SELECT *`) and the table Relevance contains 0 in both rows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `posts`
 WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('website' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4223/1)

Welcome looks like a stopword in mysql , you have to use LIKE statment for it.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM `posts`
  WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('website' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  OR    title LIKE '%Welcome%'
```

Comment: As far as I understand how `MATCH x AGAINST y` works, you can add multiple keywords, that's what I'm looking for. Otherwise I would indeed use `LIKE`

Comment: What is the difference in using `IN BOOLEAN MODE` ?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993714/mysql-like-and-boolean-mode-fulltext-search) to see what difference in BOOLEAN mode

Comment: So the BOOLEAN mode is more performant for fulltext columns? Also it'll look for every word seperatly instead of the full string. But it looks like it always returns 1.0?

Comment: if you wanna that it will look for every word separatly then consider to make`+` before every word.

Comment: check this answer for how to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572375/mysql-search-for-string-and-number-using-match-against

Answer (score 2):

Apparently 'welcome' is in MySQL's [default stopword list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

You can search for something else for testing purposes, and you can change the stopword list if you think it wont work in your case.

Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125678/mysql-fulltext-not-working?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('website' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance
FROM `posts`
WHERE `title` LIKE '%website%'
ORDER BY `Relevance` DESC
```